# Capturing windows events in C++ application

Tags: c++, windows

I need to implement a c++ program to capture the power source change event time (AC from/to DC) and do some process when the process occurs. I have seen examples using Event Tracing for Windows (ETW). Is there any other mechanism available to capture windows events?

Answer (score 0):

Create a top-level window to receive [`WM_POWERBOADCAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/wm-powerbroadcast) messages, in which you can check for [`PBT_APMPOWERSTATUSCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/pbt-apmpowerstatuschange) notifications:

> Notifies applications of a change in the power status of the computer, **such as a switch from battery power to A/C**. The system also broadcasts this event when remaining battery power slips below the threshold specified by the user or if the battery power changes by a specified percentage.

Alternatively, you can use [`RegisterPowerSettingNotification()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerpowersettingnotification) to receive `WM_POWERBROADCAST` messages containing [`PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/pbt-powersettingchange) notifications for `GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE` events:

> **The system power source has changed.** The `Data` member is a `DWORD` with values from the [`SYSTEM_POWER_CONDITION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/WinNT/ne-winnt-system_power_condition) enumeration that indicates the current power source.

---

Related: [How to get the Windows Power State Message (WM_POWERBROADCAST) when not running a Win32 GUI app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165623/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How to capture some other events(wake from sleep, modern standby etc)

Comment: For wake from sleep, read the documentations I linked to. Also see [How can I know when Windows is going into/out of sleep or Hibernate mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228288/). Unfortunately, AFAIK, there is no (known) way to detect entering/leaving "modern standby" at this time.